# Can't build C++ project with XLNT library

Tags: c++, build, compilation, libraries

I am trying to build a sample project using the [XLNT-Library](https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt) under Windows 8 using MinGW g++.
The code is the sample code found in the github Documentation:

```
#include <xlnt/xlnt.hpp>

int main()
{
    xlnt::workbook wb;
    xlnt::worksheet ws = wb.active_sheet();
    ws.cell("A1").value(5);
    ws.cell("B2").value("string data");
    ws.cell("C3").formula("=RAND()");
    ws.merge_cells("C3:C4");
    ws.freeze_panes("B2");
    wb.save("example.xlsx");
    return 0;
}
```

I downloaded the library as a zip file, extracted it and copied the folder [xlnt-master-root]\include\xlnt into the folder where my main.cpp resides and then tried to compile it with this command:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -lxlnt -Ixlnt/include .\excelTest.cpp -o excelTest.exe
```

But this results in the following error:

```
c:/users/s/documents/myprogramms/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
 cannot find -lxlnt
```

I also tried copying the [xlnt-master] folder to the main.cpp location and tried to compile it again with the same result.

I can program in C++ but I have not worked with libraries before.
Can you please give me a hint how to use and compile the project with the library correctly?

FYI: I also tried building the library with with cmake as [found here](https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt/blob/master/docs/introduction/Installation.md).
Although cmake was a success, make -j8 won't do anything because no Makefile is created in the build directory.
Maybe I went wrong here?

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the lasted **visual studio 2017**,you can build the **xlnt** library automatic.

you can download the library below:

https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvyYANq3dYDem1g9MtINWWw7CyTH